# Not appear Xamarin forms PCL projects in visual studio 2017 enterprise version 15.5.2

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I upgrade visual studio 2017 to version 15.5.2, when I create a new project of xamarin forms not show PCL (Portable Class Libraries) project that appear .net standard and Shared Projects.

I need to create some project PCL of xamarin forms, help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since a recent version the templates replace the PCL library with a .NET Standard library. And I suggest that you stick with it, as it will be the future.

You should be able to create a PCL library if you really want to and make it work. Also, as a workaround, you could create the project on Visual Studio for Mac. It doesn't have the updated templates (yet) and you will still be able to create the app with a PCL. Just copy that or commit it to source control and open it on Windows afterwards.

Comment: *"And I suggest that you stick with it, as it will be the future."* - theoretically I second that, but unfortunately there are still NuGets that ain't working with .NET standard.

Comment: Certainly true. Right now you could get in a bit of a pickle because there are NuGets that only support .NET Standard _or_ NuGets they don’t! So if you need both and they don’t align in supported platforms, then you’re out of luck right now. Of course, most plugins are open-source. So if you really rely on them, consider backing them by porting it to .NET Standard and open a PR. But still, as indicated by this move from Microsoft, everything will be moved to .NET Standard, so you’d better be prepared.